# Override Opportunity New button with Visual force not populating account name from Related List after record type selection in lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning, related-list, standardcontroller, button-overrides

I have overridden the opportunity new button with Visual force page and working all well in classic. But we enabled lightning recently and Opportunity new button is working properly but.

In lightning, when I clicked on Account related opportunity new button, it is redirecting to Record Type selection page then to visual force page and account Name getting disappeared. This is working well in classic, account getting populated after record type selection. Please find below screen shots for more information.

I feel StandardController is not retaining the values after record Type redirection. can anyone guide me how to overcome this error.

Note: This is working if there are no record types.
[image]
[image]